# What is forward drag on a coaster brake

Tags: brakes, hub, coaster

I have a single-gear coaster brake bicycle that needed fixing. I would have to pedal real hard to get it to go and backpedal a block in advance for bike to stop. Very spongy brakes. Well I took brake hub apart carefully, cleaned it, repacked with grease and reassembled it. The brakes work great now but it's harder than ever to get the bike rolling. I have to pedal so incredibly hard. Once I get to a decent speed then it doesn't feel as hard to pedal. When researching possible reasons, I kept coming across something called "forward drag", too much or too little. What is forward drag and how do I adjust this? Did I assemble it incorrectly?

Comment: Sound like something is over-tightened.

Comment: With the wheel off the bike and spinning the axle in hand, is it draggy then? (In other words can you eliminate the bearings being tight?) Are you sure the tire isn't dragging on something? Otherwise the problem sounds a little like the brake is somehow engaging at the same time as the drive, but I'm having a hard time envisioning how that would work - can you list the make/model of the hub? They differ a little in how the clutch spring inside works, but that spring being broken/distorted/weak is responsible for a large share of weird coaster brake stuff.